# Printing multiple pages per sheet on both side then divide the paper?

Tags: printing

I would like to print 4 pages per sheet, on both side of the paper, then divide (cut) the paper into 4 part. If it's just 1 sheet (which can contain 8 printed pages), I can write the print order as `1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6` so that when I divide the sheet, behind **page 1 is page 2**, **behind page 3 is page 4**, and so on..

Now I need to print hundred of pages from a document, since writing the print order simply isn't viable, how do I do this?

Document is in Word format, but I don't mind to use another program (preferably free) as long as it can receive exported files from Word.

Comment: won't the print dialog just allow you to print 100 copies at that layout?

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry I don't follow your question. I don't intend to make copies, just 1 long document to print.

Comment: ahh... one document, hundreds of pages. That wasn't clear. I'd be using QuarkExpress for that kind of task, not Word.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for the suggestion, I updated my question to clarify it. QuarkXpress is out of the question, but that does give me an idea..

Comment: do you want to make a booklet of it?

Comment: @juFo Booklet, yes, that might be the proper word to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by printing in two passes on the same pages:

1. First pass will print odd pages in horizontal-first
2. Second pass will print even pages in top-right-first order on the other side of the pages printed in the first pass.

Word can print even or odd pages, but for the second pass you will need
to go into the Printer properties page (if your printer supports it).
For my printer, this is found under Page Layout click Page Layout,
then the Specify... button (see image below).

You may also need for the second pass to put the pages into the printer
upside-down and change the print order in Word to last-page-first.

I suggest making some test runs until getting right this sequence of
operations.

Here is how the Printer properties page looks like in my printer
for the second pass:

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround! My printer doesn't support the reorder option but fortunately Adobe Reader does. One extra step but it is working very well.

Comment: @Nur better give an upvote to the answer too!